# How would I validate Typescript Typedefs using JSON Samples?

Tags: typescript, validation

I've got a project that is written in multiple languages and I've written JSON samples for all of the types that could ever need to be shared between them, In order to keep them in sync as a part of regression testing I've written some JSON sample files that each testing set should be able to parse and validate into the native representation of its languages.

This works fine in the strongly types languages where it needs to be a specific schema or it wont even parse, but `JSON.parse()` returns any.

Is there a way I can validate that a parsed JSON Object (any) is a specific type (from an interface)
noting that requirements also include keeping JSDocs, recursion, among the other basic requirements of a typescript type set.

So far I've trued `zod`, and `typia`,

`zod` didn't properly support the recursion which broke a lot of things, although when it did work it was perfect, and intentionally breaking one side or the other produced expected results.

`typia` only seems to see the `any` and say "yep, that's an object" when i asked it to compare it to an object of a different schema. I understand that that is what it does, but I'm testing the types compared to a common set of inputs, not the inputs based on the types.

In essense i need to be able to do what typica does but recursively.

the testing framework itself (currently vitest) is flexible-ish.

Comment: Update: I've given up and will just suffer writing my types twice

we love JSDoc